# laravel hasOne but multiple same ids

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have vehicles table. `(id, name, make)`

I have vehicle_prices table `(id, vehicle_id, mileage, price)`

Now, It's possible that in `vehicle_prices`, i might have the same `vehicle_id` multiple times, but all of them with different mileage. Because vehicle prices differ depending on mileage. So I have unique index on `vehicle_id` and mileage. Because of that multiple vehicle_id in `vehicle_prices`, I decided to use `hasMany` relationship. So here is something I am doing.

```
$vehicle = App\Http\Models\Vehicle::with([
            'prices' => function($query){
                $query->where('milleage', 1000)->latest('id')->first();
            })
        ])->where('id', 1)->first();
```

The thing now is that $vehicle->prices now is an array which will always have 1 object in there. why is it not just an object instead of array? I guess that's because of `hasMany` relationship.

Should I have `hasMany` or change it to `hasOne` even though `vehicle_id` might get repeated in `vehicle_prices`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get one object just use:

```
 $vehicle->prices()->first();
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-named-routes)

Comment: I need to use eager loading 'with'. What you suggested works I know, but what about my example?

Comment: $vehicle->prices; returns not array, it returns a collection, and it is same as $vehcle->prices()->get();

Comment: then you can just use: $vehicle->prices->first(); Because the prices propery is a collection and as such you'll have all the functions that are availible to the Collection object

Comment: in with relationship, i typed $query->where('mileage', 2000)->latest()->first(). you see first? why is it still returning array?

Comment: show please what returns: dd($query->where('mileage', 2000)->latest()->first());